# C# create class with dynamic number of properties

Tags: c#, class

I'm new to c# but need to have it so depending on what d equals , there are a equal number of properties so if d=3 it would be D1, D2, D3, and the same if d=10000
I don't see how I can have a dynamic name for properties that would follow this pattern.

```
Int d = 2;
class Points 
{
int D1 = 0;
int D2 = 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi. I believe what you're asking for is not possible, but if you explain what you're trying to achieve, we'll probably be able to find a workaround.

Comment: Maybe a list inside `Points` having as many elements as `d`?

Comment: Use [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).

Comment: Use a dictionary

Comment: If you need dynamic properties in c# - that mean something wrong in your design. Answer will depend not on what you need but on **how you going to use your properties?** Maybe `Dictionary<string, int>` will more then enough for you case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [DynamicObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx),  to meet your needs.

Comment: To be honest, if he's new to C#, I would expect that there is a simpler solution than that which he just hasn't thought of. Probably involving a list. I think best to avoid an answer till we know what he wants.

Comment: @YairHalberstadt: from the code provided it is clear that he wants `D#` properties inside some type where `# = N`, some natural number. Basically add dynamically properties to the type where property name itself is dynamic.

Comment: If we get even more granular - maybe OP is actually just trying to store multiple values together and needs an array?

Comment: Yes but why would he need that? Most experienced programmers only need that in rare edge cases. I can't imagine that this is really neccessary for what he's doing.